# Leaflet doesn't load negative coordinate tiles

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm learning Leaflet and I can't seem to figure out what I did (or didn't do) to make negative coordinate tiles not load.

My code currently looks like this:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
}).setView([0,0]);

L.tileLayer('img/tile_{x}_{y}.png', {
  tileSize: 100,
  noWrap: true,
  format: 'image/png',
}).addTo(map);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the most intuitive description, but it's probably the tileLayer [continuousWorld](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-continuousworld) option you're looking for.

> If set to true, the tile coordinates won't be wrapped by world width (-180 to 180 longitude) or clamped to lie within world height (-90 to 90). Use this if you use Leaflet for maps that don't reflect the real world (e.g. game, indoor or photo maps).

At least for me this worked with tiles that using the scheme "{z}_{y}_{x}.png" e.g. 1_0_-1.png, 1_-2_0.png 1_1_-1.png for a ¬ shaped map that's left of the 0,0 coordinates.

Beware that by default negative y is up and positive is down. To reverse this behavior use the [tms](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-tms) option.